# Form validation error in multiple form validation

Tags: python, django, forms

When I submit my multiple forms, I receive this POST with prefixed data:

> [(u'2-response_vote', u'3'), (u'3-response_text', u'test text'), (u'1-response_text', u'test text 3'), (u'6-response_text', u'test text'), (u'5-response_text', u'test text'), (u'4-response_vote', u'2'), (u'2-response_text', u'test text 3'), (u'7-response_radio', u'2'), (u'csrfmiddlewaretoken', u'sHMFh7NGSdD3bMwU57ZScifMJ9KKvvGT'), (u'5-response_vote', u'2')]

Here is my model:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(SampleGroup, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    response_radio = models.NullBooleanField()
    response_vote = models.IntegerField(help_text="Choisir une valeur entre 1 et 5", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    response_text = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True)
```

So, in my CBV, I have to handle this POST data and I attempt this approach:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    forms = set()
    fields_values = {}
    for k, value in self.request.POST.items():
        if 'response' in k:
            i, field = k.split('-')
            data[i][field] = value # use of defaultdic from collections

    for i, field_value in fields_values.items():
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=i)
        response = Response(question=question, **field_value)
        form = get_response_form(question)
        form = form(instance=response)

        if not form.is_valid():
            return self.form_invalid()
        forms.add(form)
```

I keep having an error:

> Form is not valid

The form is bound but not valid. Can someone explain why?

**Edit:**
Here is the special function that returns me an adapted form (that may be as far as I understand formset, unable to use them):

```
QUESTION_TYPE = {
'boolean': ['response_radio'],
'vote': ['response_vote'],
'vote_and_text': ['response_vote', 'response_text'],
'close_and_text': ['response_radio', 'response_text'],
'text': ['response_text'],
}

def get_response_form(question):
    "Returns an appropriate form"

    field_list = QUESTION_TYPE[question.question_type]

    class AdaptedResponseForm(ModelForm):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AdaptedResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.form_show_labels =  False
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset(
                    question.question_text,
                )
            )

        class Meta:
            model = Response
            fields = field_list

    return AdaptedResponseForm
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a formset?

Comment: try to use form(question=question, **field_value) instead of form(instance=response)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure to know how to use it yet !

Comment: The documentation is very helpful. As far as I can tell, it does exactly what you want without any hacking around with prefixes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The documentation is really helpfull indeed but I'm afraid I can't use a formset in my use case since I use a special method that create an adapted form depending on each parents question. I edit my first message to add this function. I thank you very much for your advise.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov Thanks, you helped me a lot because you were very close to the right solution. It is: form(field_value, instance=response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, it is not enough to bind a form with an instance. The form method is_bound returns true but the form remains invalid: is_valid() returns False. To me, the solution was to add a dictionary besides the instance.

```
form(field_value, instance=response)
```

Which is something that I definitely don't understand. May someone be kind enough to explain why the complete instance is not enough to complete the form please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly, but it seems to me, that problem is how you are using "instance" parameter in form creation. I think instance must be existing object from database, this parameter intended to edit existing  object via form, preventing creation of new object. I think you should do some refactoring on your code, you no need to create instance, just pass all field values to form directly. Something like:

```
form(field_value)
```

Comment: Actually I need to create an instance first because question has to be bind to the Response object. Instantiating response = Response(question=Question) allow me to fill response.question_id and question fields silently. If I add field_value['question': question), it fails with an unashable type error. I would be glad to see how you would refactorize it.

Comment: It's to hard fix something in one place to comb your code. Only one thing that I can propose not assume all code rewrite is to bind Response objects to Question instance after form validation, because your form doesn't validate it anyway.